# HAXM not installed error in AVD manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I understand this question has been asked earlier as well, and I have infact tried everything I could find there but I am still not able to solve the issue.

I am seeing this error when I try to run AVD.

```
"Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
HAXM is not installed.

Install Intel HAXM for better emulation performance.""
```

if I go ahead and click 'ok' it shows me the installer, I have gone through the installation step there many time withouct changing the preferred RAM size. in the end it says this.

```
"Running Intel® HAXM installer
Intel HAXM installed successfully!
Done"
```

but after restarting everything, I see the same problem again.

I ran haxm_check.exe and it says.

```
"VT support -- yes
NX support -- yes
```

I mannually downloaded the package form intel site and installed, it again says installed successfully but AVD somehow can't pick it.

No idea what should I do next.

**USING WINDOW 10 / ANDROID STUDIO 2.1.1**

[image]

**EDIT -Seeing some weird behaviour**

C:\Users\Ankit\Desktop\haxm>silent_install.bat
Intel HAXM installed successfully!

C:\Users\Ankit\Desktop\haxm>silent_install.bat -u
Intel HAXM is not installed!

Installation says it's successful, but un-installation says otherwise

Comment: Go to the in SDK Manager and click on Extras then Install intel x86 (Haxm installer) if dosnt work then your CPU graphic not support Haxm

Comment: Download the HAXM manually from here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/

Comment: already done that.. infact after that visited the downloaded localtion Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and run the file "intelhaxm-android.exe" manully, but this also didn't fixed the error

Comment: @AvihooMamka as I mentioned in the question, I have tried that as well.. that gets installed as well. but AVD still not picking it

Comment: May be you need to enable `Virtualization` from `BIOS` itself. Check if it is disable then enable it and try.

Comment: @jaydroider I have verified, Virtualization is enabled as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, seems like I solved it but still I have no idea what was the problem. Infact it's fixed accidentally.

so I had this file there intelhaxm-android.exe, I accidently opened it in winrar and there I could see hax.msi file.. I ran it and setup begun, followed it and all seems fine now.

however directly running intelhaxm-android.exe was not opening any installer setup, it was just opening a command prompt which was getting closed immidiately.

Seems like this was something very specific to my laptop..

Comment: Ya, you are right. It turns out that intelhaxm-android.exe is a self-exec zip file instead of haxm installation file.

Comment: If you install it again and again and it says installed successfully but you still can't run the avd , then install manually , download the latest release and run the setup 
https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/

Answer (score 3):

For me it solved after installing Haxm here is link

https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/